# dual boot debian and windows 11 with veracrypt

Tags: multi-boot, windows-11, veracrypt, debian-buster

I have an hp laptop with windows 11 and whole disk encryption with AES using veracrypt, is there any way to have it dual boot with [DragonOS](https://hackaday.com/2020/04/11/software-defined-radio-made-easy/) (an sdr linux distro based on debian buster) without having to wipe the whole ssd first?

I forgot to add. I can decrypt the disk, in case that may help

Comment: If you can trigger the decryption from the installer or live session then yes, it should be possible. But certainly easier is to have a virtual machine in Windows.

Comment: An SSD should be fast enough to support a Virtual Machine well. This is what I do with zero danger to the host machine

Comment: Whole disk encryption issues are one of the most frequent problems encountered on *Super User*, with the most frequent answer being, *not much can be done to fix it.* You might consider encrypting a folder or partition, to be mounted *after* booting, which also simplifies making he PC dual-boot.